# Connect mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.6

I need to know how to connect `mongodb` as primary database.

please guide me to connect the database

Comment: Try the official [tutorial](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: @DanIonescu its mongodb normal connection with python.i need with django , mongodb as backend

Comment: For django this is the [official](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) mongo way

Answer (score -1):

Install `mongoengine` app

In `settings.py` file you can add following..

add  `'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

## Defines mongodb user model for Authentication

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'

## Session storage setting

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

## Database settings as follow

```
from mongoengine import connect
connect('database_name', host='***.***.**.**', port=27017)

DATABASES = {
 'default': {
     'ENGINE': '',
     'NAME': '',
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure your database is created and you are using correct port and host IP

Comment: yes i using correct port and host,while migrate its shows error.

Comment: fine now its saying no module name mongoengine.django

Comment: did you installed `mongoengine`?  or traceback please

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_lineFile "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongoengine.django'`

Comment: i addded the traceback